# What type of Container should I use to hold a 2D Tile Based World's Tile Objects?

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I have a 2D tile based world, which is created using a simple array: World[100][100].

I plan on making the game multiplayer, so I figure it would be good to have the SERVER send the CLIENT all the tiles surrounding the player, and only the information that the CLIENT needs: What texture/sprite to render, and what position to render it.

To do this, I am assuming it would be good to make my own TILE class, which has a tileType (Grass, Sand, Water, etc.) and holds an array of 10 TileObjects.
TileObject is a class that holds three variables: objectType (Is it a Character? An Item? A tree? A rock?), an int objectID (which is linked to whatever the object actually is, so it knows the Character is "Leeroy Jenkins" and can then send Leeroy's animation & direction to the CLIENT for rendering.) and an objectPosition (X & Y from the Tile. This can extend beyond the Tile if needed.)

Although with this I am not sure how I would handle objects or characters that are larger than a single tile (such as a Dragon whose collision consumes many tiles) but it sounds like the best design.

What type of container should I use to store the TileObjects in the TILE class? Right now I have an array, but I doubt that is good for performance right? Some tiles may have 0 TileObjects, while others may have 5+. I used 10 because I severely doubt anything will ever exceed <10.

```
 class Tile
 {
private:
    TileObject TileObjects[10]; //up to 10 objects on a single tile
    TileTerrainType tileTerrainType; //GFX to display Grass, Sand, Water, Swamp, etc.
 }
```

I have read many different tutorials and books, who argue completely different container types: Vectors, Maps, Linked Lists, Arrays. I just do not know what is best to store TileObjects (some of which may move constantly, can be destroyed or added like dropping/picking up items, and some which may remain stationary like a tree or rock).

Comment: Just to clarify - You are using Tiles to represent both unmoving things (terrain types) and moving things (characters, items)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have a `map` from co-ordinates on the world to a `vector` of what things are contained at those co-ordinates in the world.

As in, if I have a class `Thing` that represents any thing that can be on a space in the game, and a class `Position` with `x` and `y` parameters, I would have this:

`map<Position, vector<Thing>>`

initialized with one `vector<Thing>`, initially empty, for every position in the game (all 10000 of them).

This gives you a useful property:

Spatial partitioning. If I want to figure out what things are around me, I just have to check in the map at nine different positions. If I were to go the other way, and have one big `list` of `Thing`s unpartitioned by where they are, I would have to look at every single `Thing` in the game to make sure I'd see every single `Thing` that might be near me.

This provides huge speedups 1) the larger the map gets 2) the more `Things` exist 3) the more and more complex kinds of local interactions you demand.

---

What if you have a `ThingID` and need to get the `Thing` associated with it, not knowing where it is? To solve this, you can have a big `map<int, Thing>` of `ThingID`s to `Thing`s and look in there. Of course, we see some redundancy here - we could either store the `Thing` in the flat map, or in the by-Position map, and have the other one just be a reference to the other (in the former case, containing just current position - in the latter case, containing just ThingID) and they must be kept in sync.

This could even lead to the 'dragon' problem being solved - if `Things` are in the flat map and merely references are stored in the by-position map, your Dragon could have one entry in the flat map and four references (one for each of the positions it occupies) in the by-position map, all pointing to the same thing. Then you just have to write code that is careful to not interact with an object twice, just because it happened to find it in two positions it was considering!

Comment: Thank you. It is nice to know there are knowledgable users that can actually answer problems. Thank you for being one of the very few users who can answer actual problems. I was losing hope, as most questions & answers are amateur at best. Your answer is professional and helps me a lot. Very grateful.

Comment: @user15875 I wouldn't consider my answer to be 'professional', it's just what I know on the subject from reading about it. I just hope it helps you conceptualize how you'll write your program. :)